How to know user has given permission of select photos and videos or allow all permission android14
I am using android 13 phone, upgraded to android 14. I want to figure out what permission my app has of gallery. It is crashing when app doesn't have allow all permission and it is accessing photo from DCIM folder.

Imagine you have an app on your phone that needs to access your photos and videos. When you first install it, your phone asks if it's okay for the app to do that. This is like giving permission. Now, on newer phones that come with Android 14 already installed, everything works smoothly because the app asks for permission, and you can select your photos and videos just fine. And when users want to access new photo it asks to grant permission again
But for some people who upgraded their older phones to Android 14, things are a bit different. When they open the app, it ask for permission to access photos and videos like it should. So, when they try to select photos or videos, It grants photos and videos permission, but when accessing new photo it is unable to retrieve and it doesn't throw errors.
The difference here is how the app handles permissions on phones that were upgraded to Android 14 versus phones that had Android 14 already installed from the beginning. On upgraded phones, the app doesn't prompt users to allow access to photos and videos, causing issues when trying to use those features.
To fix this, the app needs to be updated to properly ask for permission to access photos and videos, especially on phones that were upgraded to Android 14. How to know user has "select photos and videos permission" or "allow all" permission.
